# IONIC: How to print HTML content via Bluetooth Serial?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, printing, bluetooth

I am making a POS application. I connect my app via Bluetooth Serial to send the data to the printer. My printer is `RPP02N` Bluetooth thermal printer. I am using [Bluetooth Serial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial) plugin.

Here is my code:

```
await BluetoothSerial.clear();
await BluetoothSerial.disconnect();
let connection = await BluetoothSerial.connect(pId);
connection.subscribe(async success => {
    if (success == 'OK') {
        BluetoothSerial.write("Test Print").then(() => {
            console.log("Print finished");
            BluetoothSerial.disconnect();
          });
        } else {
          BluetoothSerial.disconnect();
        }
```

This works fine, but I have to use `raw string` for the data, something like this:

```
"     SHOP NAME     "
"  77 ABC ST, 12345 "
" ----------------- "
" <MY_________DATA> "
```

It is hard to align the content like this. I need my content to be responsive, it can be print on different paper sizes. Also it needs to be able to print image logo too.

How can I do this?

---

### Convert to image

I tried another approach by converting to image.

This is my html content:

```
<canvas>
    <h3>Shop Name</h3>
    <h5>77 ABC ST, 12345</h5>
    <hr/>
    <p>My content</p>
</canvas>
```

This is the code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

And this is inside `img.onLoad()` method:

```
img.onLoad = async() => {
    ....
    ....
    const encoder = new EscPosEncoder();
    let result = encoder
        .image(img, 320, 160, 'atkinson', 128) //width must be multiplication of 8
        .encode();

    BluetoothSerial.write(result).then(() => {
        console.log("Print finished");
        BluetoothSerial.disconnect();
    });
}
```

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esc-pos-encoder-ionic) node module to convert into `ecs pos`.

It is not working, the printer prints 1 empty line.

---

### Printing raw html

I tried to print raw html. Turns out, it really prints raw html literally (Like: `<canvas>....</canvas>`).

Answer (score 0):

For printing HTML content on Bluetooth printing you need to encode the HTML data using [esc-pos-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esc-pos-encoder-ionic).

Here are the steps to print HTML content on the Bluetooth printer.

1. Take the HTML code and append it to the body.
2. Now take the HTML node and create image of it.
3. Once image is created use esc-pos-encoder to encode the image data.
4. Send the encoded data to the printer.

```js
public print() {
    const elemId = this.prepareHtmlData(htmlStr, width);
    const node = document.getElementById(elemId);
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = async () => {
        const imgWidth = this.checkNumberMultiple(img.naturalWidth, 8);
        const height = this.checkNumberMultiple(img.naturalHeight, 8);
        const encoder = new EscPosEncoder();
        const printData = (encoder.initialize().image(img, imgWidth, height).newline().encode()).buffer;
        console.log('sending data to device...');
        await bluetoothSerial.write(printData);
        await bluetoothSerial.disconnect();
    }
    const canvas = await html2canvas(node);
    let imgSrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    img.src = imgSrc;
}
```